# Flask pytest testing database

Tags: python, flask, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy, pytest

I am trying to write some test for my application. I can manage to test URLs which does not contain anything related to db.

```
@pytest.fixture
def client():
    """
    Load pytest fixture.
    :return: test_client()
    """
    # yield application.test_client()

    db_fd, application.config['DATABASE'] = tempfile.mkstemp()
    db.create_all()
    application.config['TESTING'] = True
    client = application.test_client()

    yield client

    os.unlink(application.config['DATABASE'])
```

my test file:

```
def test_membership_register(client):
    """Test entry point of website."""
    rv = client.get('/register')

    new_user = User(
            username='test_user_1',
            email='test_email@test1.com',
            password='test1_Password',
        )

    db.session.add(new_user)
    db.session.commit()

    assert 200 == rv.status_code
```

ERROR:

E               sqlalchemy.exc.InvalidRequestError: Table 'membership_user' is already defined for this MetaData instance.  Specify 'extend_existing=True' to redefine options and columns on an existing Table object.

Comment: Where are you creating your `application` instance?

Comment: application = Flask(__name__, static_url_path='statik')